# how to stop a user from logging in twice from same account but different tab

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

I am working on a project , first i did user signup and login based on jwt authentication * note i am using reactjs * i want to disallow users from logging in several time from different tabs or browsers , what shall i do ? how to implement such service and where? i will provide the whol code that may be helpful
i want some one to help me implement not just give me the logic

This is my main express file :

```
//the main framework , express
var express = require('express');
//path , used for joining pathes
var path = require('path');
//cross origin resource sharing 
var cors= require('cors')
//body parser used to take data from forms , to be used later on
var bodyParser=require("body-parser");
//for security reasons , http security(not https)
var helmet= require('helmet')
//for parsing tokens and session cookies
var cookieParser= require('cookie-parser')
//assigning express functionaities as a global variable
const app = express()
//assigning cors functionaities as a global variable
app.use(cors())



//headers that will be sent to the browser
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ['PATCH', 'POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT']);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , '*')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers' ,'content-type')
  next();
});

//body parser for form data
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())
// secure apps by setting various HTTP headers
app.use(helmet())
// enable CORS - Cross Origin Resource Sharing
 app.options('*', cors()); 


//fetching index from react
app.use(express.static('./build/'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html')))  ;
});

//giving the functionalities of users.js to a variable users to be used later on
var Users = require('./routes/Users')
//using the functions assigned for users
app.use('/users', Users)

//exporting the app file 
 module.exports = app
```

this is the routes file which contains my controller:

```
const express = require('express')
//setting a users variable to be used as a router instead of app post , get ..
const users = express.Router()
//cross oigin resource sharing 
const cors = require('cors')
//jwt for user login authentication
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
//bcrypt for password encryption and decryption
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
//using te user model
const User = require('../model/user')
//setting users as cros origin functionalities
users.use(cors())
//privat key or jwt encryption and decryption
process.env.SECRET_KEY = 'q1w2e3r4t5y6u7i8o9p0o9i8u7y6t5r4e3w2q1'

//main signup function , exported
users.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  //setting a new user object to be manipulated and inserted to db 
  //data taken from react client side 
  const today = new Date()
  const userData = {
    username : req.body.username,
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    created: today
  }

  //a function from sequelize , a wrapper for later on functions
  //searches if the username is found or not 
  User.findOne({
    where: {
      //searching in the whhole db for this user name 
     username: req.body.username
    }
  })
    // encrypting the password using bcrypt encryption function
    //bcrypt uses a hash function to encrypt the user given password
    //will not reach this part if user is duplicated
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        //hashing the password , 10 is a number for permutations 2pwr10 = a certain string built in
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          userData.password = hash
          //creating a user with the given data
          User.create(userData)
          //send the username to the response tab in console
            .then(user => {
              res.json({ status: user.username + '    '+ 'Registered!' })
            })
            //any error will be consoled here
            .catch(err => {
              res.send('error: ' + err)
            })
        })
      } else {
        //will reach if username is found ,  User.findOne 
        res.json({ error: 'User already exists' })
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

//main login functionality
users.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  ///searches for username in db at first
  User.findOne({
    where: {
     username: req.body.username
    }
  })
  //if the user is found , it compared the password with the given password
  //it compared it the encrypted pass in the db
  //and decrypts it to compare
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        //if user name is found the deryption starts here
        if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          //each user is given a certain jwt token for authentication
          //jwt.sign , Synchronously sign the given payload into a JSON Web Token string payload
          //secret key provided above
          //token is assigned using the front end whuck sends it with the request
          let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
            expiresIn: 1440
          })
          //send token to local storage of the browser that checks it 
          res.send(token)
        }
      } else {
        //reaches here if user isnt found
        res.status(400).json({ error: 'User does not exist' })
      }
    })
    //catches any error from the above blocks
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: err })
    })
})

users.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  //Synchronously verify given token using a secret or a public key to get a decoded token token -
  // JWT string to verify secretOrPublicKey - Either the secret for HMAC algorithms, 
  //or the PEM encoded public key for RSA and ECDSA.
  // [options] - Options for the verification returns - The decoded token.
  var decoded = jwt.verify(req.headers['authorization'], process.env.SECRET_KEY)


  //searches for user
  User.findOne({
    //decode user id and jwt 
    where: {
      id: decoded.id

    }

  })
  //if true, user is sent as a json object to browser
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user)
        res.json(user)
      } else {
        //if false , send this response
        res.send('User does not exist')
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.send('error: ' + err)
    })
})

module.exports = users
```

react front end end-points:

```
 import axios from 'axios'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
//the signup endpoint sent from front end and interpreted by the browser
//route is an api called users , exported from server side
//posting user data as in server
//sending a response if true
export const signup = newUser => {
  return axios
    .post('users/signup', {
      username : newUser.username,
      first_name: newUser.first_name,
      last_name: newUser.last_name,
      email: newUser.email,
      password: newUser.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Registered')
    })
}

//login end point
//using username and password , using the decoded id 
export const login = async user => {
  try {
    const response = await axios
      .post('users/login', {
        username: user.username,
        password: user.password
      });
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', response.data);
    return response.data;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Login react page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {  withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import { login } from './api-user'


class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

//   parseJwt(token) {
//     if (!token) { return; }
//     const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
//     const base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
//     return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
// }

onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  const user = {
    username:this.state.username,
    password: this.state.password
  }

  login(user).then(res => {
    if (res) {
      this.props.history.push(`/profile`)
    }
  })
  localStorage.setItem('username',
  JSON.stringify(this.state.username))
}


  render() {
  return (



      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="text">Username</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Enter username"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              >
                Sign in
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


  )
  }
}
```

signup react page

```
mport React, { Component } from 'react'
import { signup } from './api-user'

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      username:'',
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {}
    }

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const newUser = {
      username: this.state.username,
      first_name: this.state.first_name,
      last_name: this.state.last_name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    signup(newUser).then(res => {
      this.props.history.push(`/login`)
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 mt-5 mx-auto">
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <h1 className="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="username">User Name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Enter your username"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="first_name">First name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="first_name"
                  placeholder="Enter your first name"
                  value={this.state.first_name}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="last_name">Last name</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="last_name"
                  placeholder="Enter your lastname name"
                  value={this.state.last_name}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  value={this.state.email}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
              </div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              >
                Register!
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default SignUp
```

please i asked this question before but no one helped me , some fellows gave me the logic but without the ode , i really in need of some code , what should i do ? new table to record signins ? how to connect my already found user table and if i want a new access_token table ? or should i do a flag in user table that changes (i dont know how , i just have the ideas )

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question is that you don't want your user to open the login page or the signup page if they are already signed in.

If thats the problem then a simple solution is to redirect the user to homepage/dashboard whenever they try to login if they are already authenticated.

```
<Route
exact path='/login'
render={props => this.state.isAuth ? <Redirect to='/dashboard' /> : <Login />}
 />
```

Comment: no i dont want them to login from the same account but different browser tab , i can login using the same user at the same time but from different tabs